# mapping child object in automapper

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, automapper

I have tow classes ( RolesDTO and Roles) in RolesDTO i have `List<int> idFonction` and in Roles i have `List<functions> functions` :

Class RolesDTO

```
public class RolesDTO
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<int> IdFunctions { get; set; }
    }
```

Class Role

```
public partial class Roles
    {
        public Roles()
        {
            this.Functions = new HashSet<Functions>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Functions> Functions { get; set; }
    }
```

How can i mapping `List<int> idFunctions` to `List<funtions> functions` with automapper ?

class function

```
public partial class Functions
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool Actif { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `Function` is a class with properties FirstName, LastName, and Apple?

Comment: here is Function class :
`public partial class Functions
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool Actif { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: And how `int` should be mapped to all these fields?